# Vector subtraction coordinates in rotated axes

Tags: reference-frames, coordinate-systems, conventions, rotation, geometry

I'm going through Anthony Zee's Einstein Gravity in a Nutshell and got confused on one of his points that seems to be a more general confusion about rotating axes.

Zee first defines the rotation of coordinates $(x,y)$ on an angle $\theta$ as $(x',y')$ and writes

$x' = x\cos{\theta}+y\sin{\theta}$

$y' = -x\sin{\theta} + y\cos{\theta}$

which seems fair enough, just looking at the picture of a vector from the origin in both cases.

[image]

He defines the matrix

$R(\theta) = \left(\begin{matrix} \cos{\theta} & \sin{\theta}\\-\sin{\theta}&\cos{\theta}\end{matrix}\right)$

and writes that for any point $P$, if we define $r_p$ as the vector of its $(x,y)$ coordinates and $r'_P$ as the vector of its $(x',y')$ coordinates, $r'_P = R(\theta)r_P$, which again makes sense. He then defines a point $Q$ with coordinates $r_Q$ and $r'_Q$ in each system, and subtracts $r'_Q-r'_P$ to find the coordinates of the vector between $P$ and $Q$ in the new coordinate system. His conclusion is that, if $\Delta x$ is the difference between the $x$ coordinate of $Q$ and $P$, and so on for $x'$, $y$, and $y'$,

$\Delta x' = \Delta x\cos{\theta}-\Delta y\sin{\theta}$

$\Delta y' = \Delta x \sin{\theta} + \Delta y\cos{\theta}$

which, again, drawing a picture it makes sense--the difference between the x coordinates goes down and the y goes up. But I don't see how to conciliate that with the fact that $$r'_Q - r'_P = R(\theta)r_Q - R(\theta)r_P = R(\theta)(r_Q - r_P).$$ Am I missing something?

Comment: What do you mean by "conciliate that"? What is your question? Also, to what picture are you referring? We can't see any picture in your post.

Comment: I mean that from the last equation I mentioned I'd expect $R(\theta)$ to be multiplying the difference in vectors, but the negative sign multiplying $\sin{\theta}$ is switched. About the pictures, sorry, it was a manner of speaking. I just meant "if you draw the picture" etc. I posted the first one since it's in Zee, but he didn't draw the second. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Probably something is getting confused between active vs passive rotation. Effectively it just changes the sign of $\theta$, which will change the sign of $\sin(\theta)$ but not $\cos(\theta)$

Comment: So, likely Zee's equation for $\Delta x'$ and $\Delta y'$ have the wrong sign on the $\sin$ terms. It's probably just a typo since everything else you show is a passive coordinate rotation, not active.

Comment: In theoretical physics you don't have to get the sign right every time, but if you get the sign wrong you should do it an even number of times :)

Comment: Yeah I thought that could be the issue, but it seems like Zee assumes a passive rotation throughout the whole section. So I'm not sure why the rotation matrix changed signs suddenly.

Comment: Actually I tried to set up two vectors on the rotating systems and it does seem like the formula on Zee has a typo! Thank you for the help!!

Comment: Definitely it's a typo.

Comment: We must send this typo to [Errata And Addenda For Einstein Gravity](https://www.kitp.ucsb.edu/zee/books/einstein-gravity/errata-and-addenda-einstein-gravity).

Comment: Yup I was planning on doing it! If you already did it though thank you and let me know so I don't send a repeat :) though I will say--if the intention was to have $R(\theta)$ there as normal, why did he write it out? Just to make it clear we were looking at a linear combination of sines and cosines again? I don't know, just makes me think. It does look like a typo though

Comment: No, I did not it.